# Ruby sending mail via gmail smtp

Tags: ruby, email

I'm creating a ruby script that checks the response status of an url and if it equals with 504, it sends a mail to another email address. For some reason, I get this: `/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/smtp.rb:960:in 'check_auth_response': 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbv9z (Net::SMTPAuthenticationError)`
I quadra checked the authentication data and they are valid. Maybe there can be something wrong in the code:

```
require 'mail'

options = { :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
            :port                 => 587,
            :user_name            => '<myusername>',
            :password             => '<mypassword>',
            :authentication       => 'plain',
            :enable_starttls_auto => true  }

Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method :smtp, options
end

Mail.deliver do
       to 'dude920228@gmail.com'
     from 'dude92@dude92.koding.com'
  subject 'Test'
     body 'Hurray!!! Test email!'
end
```

Oh also, I got the notice from google that a less secure app tried to access my account, so I set up that less secure apps can use my account.

Comment: I hope you solve this and write a good answer! I also had problems with this in the past, solved it by some miracle or Google devilry, and immediately forgot everything.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## If you *are* using 2 Factor Authentication

You need to create an app specific password for your application. Follow these steps:

1. Go to gmail
2. in the top right corner click on your profile icon and select 'My Account'
3. Click on 'Sign in & Security'
4. Scroll down the 'Sign in & Security' page a bit and there is a section called 'App Passwords' Click on that.
5. You should see a dropdown labelled 'Select App'. Select Mail.
6. For the 'on my device' dropdown select 'Other' and type in commandline or whatever you want to call the app.
7. Click 'Generate'. A password will be generated. Copy that password and replace the password you were using in your options hash with the generated password:

   options = { :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
   :port                 => 587,
   :user_name            => '',
   :password             => '<generated_password_for_app>',
   :authentication       => 'plain',
   :enable_starttls_auto => true  }

That should be it. I just tried this and it worked for me.

Also make sure your username is your full gmail email address.

You can also find the 'Official docs' here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en

## If you're *not* using 2 Factor Authentication

*NOTE: I think this answer is now out of date as per @EricDuminil*

> To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password. Which apparently means this answer no longer applies. Too bad.. –

Go to this link:

https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps

And select:

"Access for less secure apps"

as per:

https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

In this case you would use your normal email and password to connect.

Comment: Well, it looks like I'm out of luck: "The setting you are looking for is not available for your account.".

Comment: Looks like you're not using 2FA. I updated my answer with how to allow a 'less secure' application to connect. You'd use your regular password in this case.

Comment: To add a detail: If you *are* using 2FA, and your gmail account exists within G Suite, then the G Suite admin must also configure the organization to "Allow users to manage their access to less secure apps" in Security > Advanced security settings > Less secure apps. I needed this setting in order for the generated app password to work, despite the fact that using 2FA removes the "Less secure apps" setting from the individual person's account.

Comment: *To help keep your account secure, from May 30, 2022, ​​Google no longer supports the use of third-party apps or devices which ask you to sign in to your Google Account using only your username and password.* Which apparently means this answer no longer applies. Too bad..

Comment: Thanks @EricDuminil , I updated the answer with your comment.

Comment: @rainkinz hi, is this answer valid now, as google doesn't have a "less secure" setting available now

Comment: @momwhocode no it's not valid any more. I updated the answer a while back to state that.